# Cannot assign geometry to Button clip property

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0

I'm working on an interactive map. I'm using Silverlight 4 within VisualStudio 2010.
My problem is that I can't assign a geometry to Button Clip property:

Code:

```
bouton1.Clip = (PathGeometry)Forme.Data;
//forme is a class that inherits from Path
```

when I run my application I get an `ArgumentException`:

> The value is not included in the expected range

Answer (score 1):

Your `Path` called "Forme" has its geometry defined using the Path Mini-Language right?

This type of Geometry cannot be share by multiple elements.

The work-around is store the path data as a string in a `ResourceDictionary` accessible to both your "Forme" element and "bouton1" then assign it using `StaticResource`.  Something like:-

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="MyPath">M 10,100 C 10,300 300,-200 300,100</sys:String>
  </StackPanel.Resources>
  <Button x:Name="btn"  Content="Button" Height="150" Clip="{StaticResource MyPath}" />
  <Path Data="{StaticResource MyPath}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"  />
</StackPanel>
```

The painful downside is that the VS2010 designer doesn't grasp this and therefore doesn't apply the path.  You would need to run the app to visually see the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Although I need to create Path dynamically, so, i'll try to do that in code behind (c#).

Comment: OK... I changed button by Path and MouseLeftButtonDown event, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed button with Path and MouseLeftButtonDown event, it works :)

Comment: @StefanP The author answered his/her own question.